# JavaScript Regex Convert long date time to short date and covert long number to 2 decimal places

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

hi everyone I have a simple javascript problem and am hoping someone could help me with this

```
function changeDate(){
var date = '2/1/2013 12:00:00 AM';

var newDate = date.replace^(?ni:(?=\d)((?'year'((1[6-9])|([2-9]\d))\d\d)(?'sep'[/.-])(?'month'0?[1-9]|1[012])\2(?'day'((?<!(\2((0?[2469])|11)\2))31)|(?<!\2(0?2)\2)(29|30)|((?<=((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00)\2\3\2)29)|((0?[1-9])|(1\d)|(2[0-8])))(?:(?=\x20\d)\x20|$))?((?<time>((0?[1-9]|1[012])(:[0-5]\d){0,2}(\x20[AP]M))|([01]\d|2[0-3])(:[0-5]\d){1,2}))?)$

alert(newDate); // i need this to alert just '02/01/2013'

}


 function twoDecimalPlace{

var decimal = '1904686.92000000';
//do something;

alert(decimal) // this should alert 1904686.92
 }
```

So basically I need to truncate time and get short date.  And for the decimal place i need it to be shortened to 2 decimal places and also see if it is like 0.988 then that should be 0.99 round off to the next largest if trailing number is greater than 5

Comment: try this jquery plugin, it will help u alot i think: https://github.com/phstc/jquery-dateFormat You can parse and format dates with that

Answer (score 2):

A regular expression is not the right tool for the job.

You should use [`Date()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) then use methods like [`getDate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDate), [`getFullYear()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getFullYear), etc to reformat the date.

Comment: yes actually I am retrieving the date from server in my application and just need a simple solution to convert the long date time to short date

Answer (score 0):

As for decimal places:

```
var x = twoDecimalPlace('1904686.92600000');
alert(x);
function twoDecimalPlace(decimal){
    var result = Number(decimal).toFixed(2);
    return(result);
 }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6etNB/